# Ruby regex: match alternative expressions with quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, I want to have a regex match either of two expressions with a single group in the result. I want the following results:

```
regex = /you tell me/
regex.match(%|My name is "Peter"|)[1]
=> "Peter"
regex.match(%|My name is 'Peter'|)[1]
=> "Peter"
```

Note that I want the 1st group to refer to just `Peter` with no quotes, and I want there to be exactly one group matched in either case. Just as an example, this would match the first case (only):

```
/^My name is "([^"]*)"$/
```

I'd like something similar to that. I happen to be using this for cucumber testing.

Comment: since I'm using cucumber, this is equivalent because you're guaranteed to be matching on just a single line. Cucumber's auto-generated matchers use `^$`. In general a good point though.

Comment: Ah, then never mind, then. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This regex](http://rubular.com/r/07X4uoqvEJ) might work for you

```
['"](\w+)['"]
```

It matches exactly one group. But it also allows unbalanced quotes, like `'Peter"`

If you want to match only balanced quotes, then you can't do it with a single group (I'm afraid).

Anyhow, [here's my take](http://rubular.com/r/CFuWcQsD5q):

```
('|")(\w+)\1
```

It matches two groups and "Peter" is in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

http://rubular.com/r/C78X0wwGej

`(?=['"](\w+)['"])(?:"\1"|'\1')`